# ClassNotFoundException, while running example job of Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have started a little something on hadoop. It is setup and running properly. Right now I am doing a single node / stand alone cluster. 
I am trying to run sample job as mentioned on http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.18.3/mapred_tutorial.html

So far, program is correctly compiled, jar has been created, manifest added successfully. But when I try to run the job I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.myorg.WordCount
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
```

I have copy pasted the exact same program as mentioned in link. But it's giving this error. This is the command line I hit.

```
[shantanu@shades1ld1 hadoop]$ bin/hadoop jar /home/shantanu/hadoop/src/examples/wordcount.jar org.myorg.WordCount /tmp/Hadoop_Jobs/ /tmp/Hadoop_Results
```

I have gone through numerous articles, but couldn't find an explanation for this, please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure that `wordcount.jar` contains the `org.myorg.WordCount` class?

Didn't you modify the package name?

Comment: can you please elaborate? I am new in Java too. As an update, I removed the `package org.myorg;` statement. Now it is a single class. Still it gives me `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount`. Help !!

Comment: That's the problem. You should not remove the package name, or in the command line you should refer without it.

Comment: i have removed `org.myorg.WordCount` and made it `WordCount`, only

Comment: Deleted all setup and made new one. Suddenly everything started working. No changes were made except that I had not entered `hadoop.tmp.dir` in core-sites.xml. I think that was the problem. What do you think? And thanks for your help.

Comment: I had a similar problem, caused by my not following the directions carefully, specifically, deciding to not use the -d option. Doh!

Answer (score 11):

I found that I needed to add this to the sample app to get hadoop to know what jar my class files are in.

```
diff --git a/src/org/myorg/WordCount.java b/src/org/myorg/WordCount.java
index 912311a..8cc1b93 100644
--- a/src/org/myorg/WordCount.java
+++ b/src/org/myorg/WordCount.java
@@ -43,7 +43,8 @@ public class WordCount {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Configuration conf = new Configuration();

     Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");
+    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

     job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
     job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

I'm not sure if this is new for hadoop or not, but setJarByClass will tell hadoop to use an entire jar based on a single class that is contained in that jar file.  The jar must still be in your classpath.  This is the command that I ran:

```
hadoop jar wordcount.jar org.myorg.WordCount /usr/$USER/wordcount/input /usr/$USER/wordcount/output
```

And I'd previously copied the sample files into the HDFS using this command:

```
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal input/file01 /usr/$USER/wordcount/input/file01 
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal input/file02 /usr/$USER/wordcount/input/file02 
hadoop dfs -ls /usr/$USER/wordcount/input
```

where input/file01:

```
Hello World Bye World
```

and input/file02:

```
Hello Hadoop Goodbye Hadoop
```

I put up a [github repo](https://github.com/tednaleid/hadoop-wordcount) with instructions on what I was able to get working.

Comment: Thanks, It is worth to update hadoop wiki http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount. I will trust that google will find wiki link and this answer for next guy.

Comment: At 4:30 am, you saved me :D