# ClassNotFoundException, while running example job of Hadoop also

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, command

I saw the post and followed the process. But it didn't work.
[ClassNotFoundException, while running example job of Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488554/classnotfoundexception-while-running-example-job-of-hadoop/14314172#14314172)

**Help me please.**

1. created **mapreduce-0.1-tests.jar**( there is actually a MapReduceTest.class)
2. copied input file form local > hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal input /Users/test/Documents/movie_titles_only.csv
3. hadoop jar /Users/test/project/mapReduce/target/**mapreduce-0.1-tests.jar** MapReduceTest -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 input/movie_titles_only.csv movie_output

BUT!! It was same the message... How do I do, help me please!!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MapReduceTest at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
```

Comment: Can you check the package of your MapReduceTest class? (my.org.MapReduceTest?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `job.setJarByClass` to specify your jar. Add the following statement in your codes:

```
job.setJarByClass(MapReduceTest.class);
```